# Why can't I puts an instance variable of a Ruby class if it contains the value of a variable in a module?

Tags: ruby, variables

When I try to run this code, nothing or `nil` shows up. I can't seem to understand why, since I thought classes that include modules can access its instance/class variables. I can print out the value just fine if I don't use `garbtest` and just use the `garb=` method to assign it a different value. It works fine without assigning it another value since I initialized it to `16` too. Is there something about the instance/class variables in the module Test that makes it equal to nil? Furthermore, when I try to assign `garb` to `@myg` + `@@vit` it says there is no such method for the `nil` class. I think this further confirms my suspicion that those variables are somehow `nil`. Thank you.

```
module Test
  RED = "rose"
  BLUE = "ivy"
  @myg = 9
  @@vit = 24.6
end
class Xy
  include Test;
  def initialize(n)
    @garb = n
  end
  attr_accessor :garb;
  def garbTest
    @garb = @myg;
  end
  def exo
    return 50;
  end
end

ryu = Xy.new(16);
ryu.garbTest;
puts "#{ryu.garb}";
```

Comment: BTW, you do not need to end lines with semicolons in ruby.

Comment: I know. I just got used to it from Java. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `@myg` is not shared variable. It is private property of module `Test`, thus while you included `Test`, `@myg` didn't come into `Xy` due to the *mixin*, it wouldn't come also by default. But, "Why nil?" - Because, instance variable, class variables are like that. Before initialising/defining them, if you attempt to use them, it will simply give you `nil`.

Small program to prove myself and Ruby :-

```
module Test
  @x = 10
  @@y = 11
end

class Foo
  include Test
end

Foo.instance_variable_defined?(:@x) # => false
Test.instance_variable_defined?(:@x) # => true
Foo.class_variable_defined?(:@@y) # => true
Test.class_variable_defined?(:@@y) # => true
```

You can define *reader* method inside `Test` singleton class, and then you can use it. Look below

```
module Test
  class << self
    attr_reader :myg
  end

  RED = "rose"
  BLUE = "ivy"
  @myg = 9
  @@vit = 24.6
end

class Xy
  include Test

  def initialize(n)
    @garb = n
  end

  attr_accessor :garb

  def garbTest
    @garb = Test.myg
  end

  def exo
    return 50
  end
end

ryu = Xy.new(16)
ryu.garbTest # => 9
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know the instance variables of the module were also private. Just two questions, though: why did you put class << self? Is that to give class characteristics to the module? Secondly, why can class variables be accessed from the module without a getter method? Is that just the default behavior of modules?

Comment: @user3828080 *I didn't know the instance variables of the module were also private* - Not only *modules*, but for *classes* too. `class << self` I Opened the *singleton class* of module `Test` and define there `reader`, so that you can invoke them on `Test`, otherwise it will be again for `instances` of those class, which will mix `Test`. *Secondly, why can class variables be accessed from the module without a getter method?* -- Matz knows better. :-) Again it is a feature, true both for class as well as for modules.

Comment: *Is that just the default behavior of modules?* - It is *hardcoded* language feature. You can't get rid of it. Hope I am able to clear your doubts.