# How do I access an instance variable from a module that was included dynamically?

Tags: ruby

I am dynamically including a module into the `Baz` class in the `foobarbaz` method.

However, when I execute this in ruby, I get a nil `puts`. Doesn't the module have access to `Foo`'s instance variables?

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :current_session

  def initialize(current_session)
    @current_session = current_session
  end

  def foobarbaz
    Baz.send(:include, Bar) # For Ruby < 2.1
    # Baz.include(Bar) # For Ruby > 2.1
  end
end

class Baz
end

module Bar
  def foobar
    @current_session
    # 'foobar'
  end
end

puts Foo.new('current_session').foobarbaz.new.foobar # nil
```

NOTE, for this, I was using Ruby 2.0.0. The following also does not `puts` desired result in Ruby 2.1.2.

Comment: @current_session in Baz is not initialized. current_session lives in the Foo instance, not the Baz instance.

Comment: your output should be??

Comment: This isn't about inheritance - you're creating a new instance of Baz, therefore it has it's own set of instance variables (would be the same if your foobarbaz method created an instance of Foo)

Comment: @ArupRakshit output should be 'current_session'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a *meta programming* for you :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Foo
  attr_accessor :current_session

  def initialize(current_session)
    @current_session = current_session
  end

  def foobarbaz
    session = current_session
    Bar.module_eval { @current_session = session }
    Baz.send(:include, Bar)
  end
end
```

[`module_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-module_evall) says

> Evaluates the string or block in the context of mod, except that when a block is given, constant/class variable lookup is not affected....

Thus inside `Bar.module_eval { @current_session = session }`, `@current_session` is the instance variable of `Bar` only and I am setting the value of it to the instance variable value of the class `Foo`, which is `@current_session`.

`Baz.send(:include, Bar)` is helpfull, which returns **class/module** itself, which is including the other module. [`include(module, ...) → self`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-include).

```
class Baz
end
```

Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24691053/why-cant-i-puts-an-instance-variable-of-a-ruby-class-if-it-contains-the-value-o/24691086#24691086) to understand the below stuff.

```
module Bar
  class << self
    attr_reader :current_session
  end

  def foobar
    Bar.current_session
  end
end

puts Foo.new('current_session').foobarbaz.new.foobar
# >> current_session
```

**Update**

As [@Christian Fazzin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702572/how-do-i-access-an-instance-variable-from-a-module-that-was-included-dynamically/24702956?noredirect=1#comment38321553_24702956) gave a good suggestion :-

If you want `Bar` module to have write method also, then you have to do 2 changes -

- `Bar` should contain then `attr_accesor :current_session`, instead of what it has now.
- You don't need to use the power of `module_eval` there, rather use *syntactic sugraness* of write methods, like put `Bar.current_session = current_session` inside the method `foobarbaz` . Remove the lines `session = current_session` and `Bar.module_eval { @current_session = session }`.

Comment: Please ask me.. If you have problem to understand this.,.. I will edit.

Comment: Always great answers!

Comment: Great answer! Instead of using `Bar.module_eval { @current_session = session }`, could we use `Bar.current_session = @current_session`? using `module_eval` seems a bit too much? I tend to stay away from anything `eval` unless necessary. That way I don't need to declare a `session` variable as well. One less line of code

Comment: @ChristianFazzini Thanks for your review and thought. (This is why, it is called meta). Your *meta knowledge* is much stronger than me.. :-) –

Answer (score 1):

After creating an instance of `Foo` (`foo`, say) and in doing so initializing `foo`'s instance variable `@current_session` to `'current session'`, it appears to me that you want `foo.foobarbaz` to do the following:

- cause `Baz` to `include` the module `Bar`
- create an instance of `Baz` (`baz`, say)
- create an instance variable named `@current_session` for `baz` and assign it the value of `foo`'s instance variable of the same name
- invoke `baz.foobar` to return the value of `baz`'s instance variable `@current_session`.

If my understanding is correct, we can perform these four steps with four lines in `Foo#foobarbaz`:

```
class Baz
end

module Bar
  def foobar
    @current_session + ' in Baz'
  end
end

class Foo
  attr_accessor :current_session

  def initialize(current_session)
    @current_session = current_session
  end

  def foobarbaz
    Baz.include(Bar)
    baz = Baz.new
    baz.instance_variable_set(:@current_session, self.current_session)
    baz.foobar  
  end
end

foo = Foo.new('current session')
foo.foobarbaz
  #=> "current session in Baz"
```

I've slightly modified what `foobarbaz` returns to show where it is coming from.

Note that the third line of `foobarbaz` could be changed to either of the following

```
baz.instance_variable_set(:@current_session, @current_session)
baz.instance_variable_set(:@current_session,
      instance_variable_get(:@current_session))
```

If the latter of these were used, `@current_session`'s accessor would not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You'd just need to set instance variable (not class instance variable!) `@current_session` of class `Baz`.

With slightest modification of your code without need of additional class/module methods the most straightforward way is to define initialization method that sets the required variable:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :current_session

  def initialize(current_session)
    @current_session = current_session
  end

  def foobarbaz
    # define Baz#initialize on-the-fly, alternatively with define_method
    Baz.class_eval "def initialize; @current_session = '#{@current_session}';end"
    Baz.send(:include, Bar) # For Ruby < 2.1
  end
end

class Baz
end

module Bar
  def foobar
    @current_session
    # 'foobar'
  end
end

puts Foo.new('current_session').foobarbaz.new.foobar
# current_session
```